# user id is Mxing when submit a form by two users at two computer at same time

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have a client application with more than ten users who can perform the same actions at same time like a filling a form, the issues comes when two users at same time submit the same form with different data's then the both data get saved by the user who clicked just a millisecond after the other user i have been placing the userid in session, and i also tried by placing userid in user.identy.name and cookies but the result is same please help me! :)

Code:

```
GetCustomerDetails() 
{ 
    Customer_Details custDetails = new Customer_Details(); 
    custDetails.Name = txtName.Text.Trim(); 
    return custDetails; 
} 

GetEntrepreneurshipDetails() 
{ 
    Entrepreneurship entre = new Entrepreneurship(); 
    ... 
    entre.AdvId = Guid.Parse(Session["userId"].ToString()); 
    return entre; 
} 

btnSubmit_Click 
{ 
    var custDetails = GetCustomerDetails(); 
    var = GetEntrepreneurshipDetails ();
    _advisorService.InsertEntreprenuershipDetails(custDetails, entreprenuershipDetails); 
}
```

Comment: sharing some code will help a lot with giving advices e.g. to locking rows

Comment: Just to clarify, 1 full set of form data gets saved from 1 user and the other user's data isn't saved? The title implies that the data is somehow getting mixed together.

Comment: GetCustomerDetails()
        {
            Customer_Details custDetails = new Customer_Details() ; custDetails.Name = txtName.Text.Trim(); return custDetails;
        }
GetEntrepreneurshipDetails()
        {
            Entrepreneurship entre = new Entrepreneurship();
            ..
            entre.AdvId = Guid.Parse(Session["userId"].ToString());
            return entre;
        }
  btnSubmit_Click        {
 var custDetails = GetCustomerDetails(); var = GetEntrepreneurshipDetails ();
  _advisorService.InsertEntreprenuershipDetails(custDetails, entreprenuershipDetails);
        }

Comment: @sr28 right only one form data is getting saved by the id of other user.

Comment: @sr28 sorry i actually mean like you said.

Comment: Not sure if you're using MVC or not, but the best thing to do is create a viewmodel with a method in it named post.  when the post comes and everything isValid, call the post method and put a lock on the critical sections that must be completed prior to returning the post back state to the user.

Comment: So if user A clicks submit a millisecond before user B then their details are saved with their user Id or are they saved but with user B's user id?

Comment: @JohnPeters i am using webform

Comment: @sr28 Record of A get saved with the id of B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to implement some sort of versioning check.

I usually create a `timestamp` field on the table (a date time), which is automatically updated by the RDBMS every time a data is saved in a record.

So, when the user comes to edit a record, I read that value and keep it. When the user confirm the operation, inside a isolated transaction, I compare the previous read timestamp value with the current one

- if both are equal, I save the new values (thus no data has been changes on that record)
- otherside, I return an alert to the current user, stating he/she will need to re-do the operation, as someone else changed the data recently

Comment: thanks rubens if found out the problem and it is because it is updating the records immediately after the insertion and in the updation i am not passing the userid